# How would I use <MATH> HTML to generate code shown below

Tags: html, math

The code I wish to learn how to code with HTML `<Math>` is in the table below
They want more details:

1. Coding parenthesis around fractions
2. Coding fractions
3. Coding radical signs (third root in the example)
4. Coding exponential notation (I used `x<sup>`y`</sup>`)

…

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .M {
        vertical-align: middle
    }

    OLi {
        text-decoration: overline;
        display: inline
    }

    /* used for top of radical sign */
    BF {
        font-size: 180%
    }

    /* for large parentheses around fractions */
    .TF {
        border-bottom: 2px solid black
    }

    /* to put fraction line below numerator */
    .C {
        text-align: center
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="font-size: 14pt; font-family; New Times Roman">
        <colgroup>
            <col span='2' style='min-width:4in'>
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class='M'>
                <table class='MATH'>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan='2'>log<sub>b</sub>
                            <BF>(</BF>
                        </td>
                        <td class='TF C'>&radic;<sup>3</sup>
                            <OLi><i>x</i></OLi><i>y</i><sup>4</sup>
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan='2'>
                            <BF>)</BF> = log<sub>b</sub> &radic;<sup>3</sup>
                            <OLi><i>x</i></OLi> + log<sub>b</sub> <i>y</i><sup>4</sup> -
                            log<sub>b</sub> <i>z</i><sup>5</sup>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='C'><i>z</i><sup>5</sup></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class='M' style="position:relative; top:8px">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan='2'>since log<sub>b</sub></td>
                        <td class='TF C'><i>mn</i></td>
                        <td rowspan='2'> = log<sub>b</sub> <i>m</i> +
                            log<sub>b</sub> <i>n</i></sup> - log<sub>b</sub> <i>p</i></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='C'>
                            <i>p</i></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't done much of maths in html. But, I can suggest you to use a javascript library, you can try https://www.mathjax.org/ . Its pretty cool from the docs. You should be able to use reading docs.